# Hashing password algorithm

Tags: c++, authentication, encryption

I'm trying to create a system in c++ to allow users to log into an account for a personal project and I want to encrypt and store usernames and passwords, but can't figure out how to do so. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how encryption algorithms work, but to no avail. I also need it to be able to ensure there are no username clashes. This means being able to read usernames from a document and compare them. I am fairly new to code so if you could dumb it down for me that would be appreciated. I would be grateful for any and all help. Thanks.

This is what I have so far, it's not much but I'm trying not to make it too convoluted until I can figure out how to make it work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


class newUser {
public:
    void signUpAttempt() {
        cout << "Pick a Username\nUsername: ";
        cin >> newUserAttempt;
        if (newUserAttempt == "existing username") {


        }

    }
private:
    string newUserAttempt;
};
bool login() {
    string isNew;
    string userNameGuess;
    
    //checks if the user already has an account
    cout << "Have you played before? (y/n)\n";
    getline(cin >> ws, isNew);
    transform(isNew.begin(), isNew.end(), isNew.begin(), ::tolower); // transforms to lower case
    
    if (isNew == "y" || isNew == "yes") {
        newUser Obj1; // creates object
        Obj1.signUpAttempt();
    }
    
    //ask for username and password
    cout << "Enter Username and Password.\n Username: ";
    cin >> userNameGuess;
    
    return true; // tells main that user is logged in.
}

int main() {
    while (login() != true) {
        login();
    }

}
```

Comment: *I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how encryption algorithms work* --  If your goal is to add encryption to your application, get yourself an encryption library and learn how to use it.  You shouldn't get into the business of trying to write your own functions -- there is a huge risk in getting something wrong if you try to do this yourself.  Leave it to the encryption experts who have written such libraries, where a programmer just needs to call the correct functions.

Comment: you can store user names in plain text, and store hashes (not encrypted) of their passwords

Comment: This is a good [Portable C++ Hashing Library](https://create.stephan-brumme.com/hash-library/) , just call the `sha256` function to create a hash of your password, you just need to store the hash. When the user enters their password again and you need to check it, just create the hash, if the two hashes match then the passwords are highly likely the same.

Comment: Just to make my point clearer, there is nothing wrong in learning how the encryption algorithms work.  There will be a *huge* problem if you attempt to write your own, you get something wrong, and either the encryption code is broken, or someone has found a vulnerability in your code and exploits it.   So it is much more than not having you reinvent the wheel -- there is actual risk in trying to reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: A cryptographer would probably use something like format preserving encryption for the username and possibly something like PFE + tweak to encrypt the password. Note that storing passwords is generally not what you want to do, ever, even if they get encrypted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, fair enough, I will look into that, however this program is designed as a way to learn new aspects of the language, it's almost certainly not going to end up online.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it is unlikely to ever end up online and isn't protecting any valuable data, so I'm not entirely sure it matters if I store passwords if they're encrypted, Thanks for the tip though.